# Reference type null checking

Tags: c#, exception, methods, null

Should I check every single reference type argument passed to a method that it is not null?

Option 1, without checking:

```
public void Foo(A a, B b)
{
    a.DoSomething();
    b.DoSomething();
}
```

Option 2, with checking:

```
public void Foo(A a, B b)
{
    if (a is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    if (b is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    a.DoSomething();
    b.DoSomething();
}
```

I also have tried something like that, but it doesn't work at all

```
public void Foo(A a, B b)
{
    Contract.Requires(a is not null);
    Contract.Requires(b is not null);

    a.DoSomething();
    b.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Are you using the Nullable Reference Types feature? Do you trust it?

Comment: What is `Contract.Requires` and why doesn't it work?

Comment: Another alternative:  `a?.DoSomething(); b?.DoSomething();` to just ignore any null, without raising any exception.

Comment: gunr2171, no I don`t use the nullable reference types. But we still can assign to a non-nullable reference type a null value (even though it would be marked with a warning). Should I check that non-nullable reference arguments are not null or just trust the warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't expect the value to be nullable, you definitely want to throw an argument exception when it is null. But that doesn't mean you have to add a bunch of extra code.

I'm personally a fan of enabling Nullable Reference Types, turning nullable warnings into compiler errors, and enabling Fody NullGuard on whatever types/assemblies/projects you want to add this behavior to. NullGuard will add code to your compiled assembly to throw exceptions if non-null arguments or return values are null.

Comment: I see `NullReferenceException` as my FRIEND. It tells me exactly where I'm doing wrong. Some people might be attempted to use code like `string bla = ""` instead, then they  have no exceptions but wrong values, which are much harder to debug.

Comment: @PoulBak: Yes, exceptions are our friends. `NullReferenceException`s are usually thrown because the code made an incorrect assumption. I like to make those assumptions explicit, and test them as early as possible. "Where I'm doing wrong" in this case isn't the line that says `a.DoSomething()` in `Foo`: it's the line where someone passed a null value into `Foo` in the first place. I like having an `ArgumentNullException` that includes the name of the argument that was null.